# Forward domain alias to a certain page

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012, domain-aliasing

We have a domain (domain.com) that has an alias (alias.com). We are using Plesk and a Windows Server. In Plesk, alias.com is setup as an alias for domain.com.

We need that when people access to alias.com it goes to a certain page within the main domain, for example domain.com/this-page.html.

The web site is an ASP.NET MVC web site, in case we can do something using the web.config.

Is this possible? How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Open web.config in the directory where the old pages reside
Then add code for the old location path and new destination as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="services.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://example.com/services" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="products.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://example.com/products" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```